# Emulator is giving Full Queue, lose event after wake up keyevent

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I'm trying to test my code after sleep and wake up.

I run this code to make emulator sleep:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER
```

Then I run

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP
```

After that, emulator stucks for a minute. After 1 minute, it starts to log

```
Emulator: ##KBD: Full queue, lose event
```

On every screen tap.

What should I do?